# Who is doctor Who?

Tags: doctor-who

I am not from a country that regularly airs Doctor Who, and I wanted to know, what is doctor who's original name?

Does anybody knows this secret ?

Wikipedia said it was unrevealed, but I myself have seen doctor saying that he knows his name(obviously).

Also, I thought, Wikipedia is edited by the people, and it is not straight from the horse' mouth.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who

Comment: Is my question that bad ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you got downvoted: I thought you were new to the show so didn't have a clue where to begin finding the information.

Comment: I downvoted because it's a very lazy question. Two seconds of googling would have led you to any one of 50 sites where you can learn all about the history of Dr Who.

Comment: That's true. To be fair when he asked I thought he wanted the specific information for a purpose that wasn't personal (for a friend, or an assignment or something), and that he hand't a clue about the show at all. It seems Amit Joki does watch the show, so I would suggest he follow Richard's link to find more information on Doctor Who than I could ever say or even know.

Comment: This was quite a googleable question.

Comment: This might be the first "general reference" I've ever seen here. VTC.

Comment: Hm. I've not been here ages myself. Was I wrong to directly answer his question?

Comment: Guys, googling gave me nothing on the Doctor's name.

Comment: To be fair the fourth paragraph on Wikipedia says: ""The Doctor" is not the character's true name, which has been left unrevealed"

Comment: Yup. And googling "what is doctor who's name" gives you this as the first answer; http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Doctor

Comment: I might have to edit my answer: according to that wikia River Song knows his name: I thought she didn't.

Comment: [Who is Doctor Who?](http://www.whoisdoctorwho.co.uk/index1.shtml)

Comment: @MacCooper - You weren't wrong to answer it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Doctor comes from a planet called Gallifrey: he is a Time Lord. His name has never been said on the show. He knows what it is but he chose the title Doctor to go by. If I remember rightly even his wife (River Song) doesn't know his name. Once Clara said it wasn't important what his name was because he goes by the Doctor and that is what he is: a healer, a helper, and he doesn't need any other name.

Oh, and I know you probably just called him "Doctor Who" so we know who you're talking about, but that isn't his title. It's simply "The Doctor", or "Doctor" when to his face. In the first few series the credits listed him as Doctor Who but never in the show that isn't his title.

As for who knows his secret, in real life: nobody has said they do so it seems that nobody does. Due to the nature of a long running show with multiple writers the current showrunner can put his name in whenever he wants. I don't think he actually has a cannon name because that's part of the characterisation: no showrunner has ever included a name for him.

Comment: Well, I'm from India, and they aren't telecasting BBC entertainment. I miss the series very much. Is there a way out ?

Comment: Out of India? Yeah

Comment: The subsciption to an online video site will be less than a ticket to England and back every saturday night. Then again...

Comment: Actually, in _The War Games_ WOTAN says multiple times, "Doctor Who is required!" The first couple of times you _could_ interpret it as: "Doctor, who is required," but the later ones were definitely calling him "Doctor Who" on-screen. I think WOTAN must have been reading the opening titles...

Comment: @CJDennis, well obviously WOTAN was referring to the show! I agree, /doctor who/ is a much needed show ;-) nah but I didn't know that. Feel free to edit it in if you like, I'm none too familiar with the original seasons myself :)

Comment: Whoops! I wrote the wrong title! _The War Games_ is the Second Doctor's final story. I meant _The War **Machines**_, a First Doctor story!